# Truffle fails to test ERC20 approval

Tags: truffle, erc-20, testing

A am implementing a custom ERC20 token inheriting from [OpenZeppelin's StandardToken](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol). I override some of the functions but did not override `approve` or `allowance`. I write a test for approval:

```
contract('MyToken', async(accounts) => {
it("approve test", async() => {
    let token = await MyToken.deployed();

    let approveResult = await token.approve.call(accounts[1], 20, {from: accounts[0]});
    assert.isTrue(approveResult);

    let allowanceAccountZeroAccountOne = await token.allowance.call(accounts[0], accounts[1]);
    assert.equal(allowanceAccountZeroAccountOne.toNumber(), 20);
  });
});
```

I get the following result:

```
  Contract: MyToken
    1) approve test
    > No events were emitted

  1 failing

  1) Contract: MyToken approve test:
     AssertionError: expected 0 to equal 20
      at Context.it (test/mytoken.js:51:12)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

It seems that `approve` returns `true`, as expected, but the subsequent `allowance` returns `0` instead of `20`. What could be the problem?

PS I tested the contract manually in [Remix](http://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05.js), and it works as expected.

Comment: remove .call from token.approve , `call` doesn;t make state changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
let approveResult = await token.approve.call(accounts[1], 20, {from: accounts[0]});
```

To

```
let approveResult = await token.approve.sendTransaction(accounts[1], 20, {from: accounts[0]});
```

Comment: Ok, but then I get `AssertionError: expected <hash> to be true`. Seems that `sendTranscation` returns the tx hash; how do I get the return value as defined in Solidity code?

Comment: True, if I comment out `assert.isTrue(approveResult);`, everything works :) Just a follow-up question, don't quite understand what I should use instead of `toNumber` for booleans.

Comment: @SergeiTikhomirov you check allowance later. sendTransaction doesn’t return solidity returned value.

Comment: @SergeiTikhomirov try toString. And in future just check with console.log returned value.